# How do I code a page to insert images in a div on keyboard event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

I'm working on a set of animated GIF images that double as a sort of alphabet.
They're still work in progress, but for display purposes I'd like to have a page on my website where you can use the keyboard to write text using the alphabet.

In simple terms, I'd like each letter key on the keyboard to be associated with an image so that, when pressed, that image would then appear on screen (inside a div, which would act as the "text box"), kind of like using a font?

Is there a library or addon that would make this really easy?

If not, any suggestions for coding would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want them as images? If it is for styling, why not just use web fonts?

Comment: They are animated GIFs @QuetiMporta - it's a kinetic typography!

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like this can be easily achieved by jQuery. As the question itself is very open, I'm not bothering writing any code, but your steps could look like this:

1. add a `onkeydown` / `onkeypress` eventListener to the document, which calls a function `keyPressed`
2. In the `keyPressed` function, check which key has been clicked. You can find the key codes [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm).
3. I would just call the images with the key codes you expect. For example the image with the letter 'A' would be called 65.gif, and son on.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#textbox').keypress(function(event) {
    if ( event.which == 13 )
        event.preventDefault();

    $(document.body).append('<img src="' + String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode) + '.gif">');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Turn your pictures into a web font. https://www.google.com/?q=online+font+creator#q=online+font+creator
- Use the @font-face CSS to import your font. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/
- Set the font-family CSS on a TEXTAREA or a CONTENTEDITABLE DIV

Comment: Hi @LastCoder  , thanks for this, only one problem: the link for turning pictures into webfonts doesn't really direct to an online font creator?

Comment: @CasperF - You don't need to use an "online" font creator, any font creation tool will be fine. Once you have a font file then you will need to "convert" it to a few formats like TTF, EOT so that you have compatibility with most browsers.